# How to get the value of Hadamard matrix given its column and row index?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, hadamard-product, hadamard-matrices

Please refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix for the Sylvester's construction of Hadamard matrix.

Given a Hadamard matrix $H\in R^{n\times n}$, then how to get the value of $H_{ij}$ via a math function like $f(i,j)$?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it looks as follows: Let $n=2^k$ and write the indices (from $0$ to $2^{k}-1$) in binary form: $i=i_0+2i_1+ ... 2^{k-1} i_{k-1}$ and $j=j_0+2j_1+ ... 2^{k-1} j_{k-1}$.
Then 
$$ f(i,j)=\left( -1 \right)^{i_0j_0 + ... + i_{k-1}j_{k-1}} $$

Comment: Thanks. Yes this is correct. But I also remember that  it can use i, j and 'mod' operation to get the desired answer. Now I just forgot....